# Is it okay to use int instead of a size_t in looping over a vector?

Tags: c++, warnings, unsigned, signed

If I have an integer vector

```
vector<int> vec;
```

and I loop in the following way

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
{
   // do something
}
```

I get the signed/unsigned mismatch warning.

Of course I can declare `i` of type `size_t` to solve the problem. 
But if I keep `i` as `int` could I get some problem at runtime?

Comment: What is your motivation for using the wrong type for `i`?  You don't mention **why** you want to use `int`.

Comment: What if `vec.size()` was greater than the positive range of `signed int`?

Comment: I think more generally, you'd want to use `std::vector<int>::size_type` (which I imagine is almost always `size_t`, but still).

Comment: @DrewDormann I have some old code written by someonelse in which all the loop variables are int and I wanted to know if it could generate errors at runtime.

Comment: You can also avoid this problem entirely with `for(int val:vec)`

Comment: @Drew: Won't that be exactly the same problem, if vec is bigger than 2^31-1?

Comment: @MatsPetersson No.  `int` serves a different purpose there.

Comment: Ok. Not that hot on C++11 yet..,.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that a vector<int> of size > INT_MAX would be impossible because you'd have run out of memory before then. So in practice the code is ok.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: With some additional complications, `for (X val:vec) { ... }` is basically defined to be equivalent to `for(auto it = begin(vec), itend = end(vec); it != itend; ++it) { X val = *it; ... }` (where `it` and `itend` aren't those exact symbols, they can be implementation-reserved symbols or be entirely hidden by the compiler). So the `int` in Drew's code is the type of the (copy of the) element, not the type of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if `vec.size()` is larger than than the maximum value for a signed int.

You can find maximum values in `limits.h` per [this table](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

Comment: All the answers are good. So I'll choose the oldest one. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

Use the vector `iterator` instead.

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it = vec.begin(); it!= vec.end(); ++it)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: +1.  OP/readers of this question should definitely be informed of this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For big numbers more than a value which a `signed` can store, it will be an undefined behavior.

However for small numbers which can be store in a `signed` it's OK.